# how to include the below rows in Dataframe.roll(3).sum() and not the rows above

Tags: python, dataframe

I would like to roll and sum my datafram "df_ts" with the window of 3. However the roll() only considers the row below and not above.

df_ts['XCorSum']= df_ts['AccXCorrected'].rolling(3,min_periods=1).sum()

expected result

### AccXCorrected| XCorSum

0                                                  3
1                                                   6
2                                                   9
3                                                   12
4                                                   9
5                                                   5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code works for me:

```
df_ts['XCorSum'] = (df_ts['AccXCorrected'].iloc[::-1].rolling(3,min_periods=1).sum().iloc[::-1])
```